# cannot find symbol when defining my own exception

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

can someone tell me why am i getting "cannot find symbol" while compiling.

This is how i define my own exception:

```
public void setIdNumber(int i)throws InvalidEmployeeId
  {
  idNumber = i;

   if ((idNumber <= 0))
     {
        throw new InvalidEmployeeId("invalid ID. Please input numeric ID");
     }

  }
```

cannot find symbol:

`public void setIdNumber(int i)throws InvalidEmployeeId`

`symbol:   class InvalidEmployeeId`

Here is the try and catch statement in the demo program:

```
 try 
   {
     id = Integer.parseInt(input);
     worker.setIdNumber(id);
   } catch (invalidEmployeeId e)
   {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
```

thanks in advance;

Comment: How have you defined your `InvalidEmployeeId` class ?

Comment: Java is case sensitive `invalidEmployeeId ` is not equal to `InvalidEmployeeId `.

Comment: Pradeep Simha: good catch, thanks. but i'm still getting the same error after i change i to I.

Comment: _This is how i define my own exception:_ No, you are not defining your own exception with this code.

Comment: BackSlash: well that line is not a part of the program, buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Add this class to your code:

```
public class InvalidEmployeeId extends Exception
{

public InvalidEmployeeId(String string)
{
    super(string);
}

}
```

Just saying new does not define the `Exception` for you. Furthermore, you must be consistent in your usage of the class names.

```
try 
 {
 id = Integer.parseInt(input);
 worker.setIdNumber(id);
 } catch (InvalidEmployeeId e) //must be a capital I!
 {
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
```

If you **already defined** an `ivalidEmployeeId` `Exception` subclass, then you must change this line:

```
 throw new invalidEmployeeId("invalid ID. Please input numeric ID");
```

Comment: I think he already have it, his problem is `catch(invalidEmploteeId)`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yeah, one of those names is definitely wrong...

Comment: i changed i to I, however, still getting the same error

Comment: @user3080461 Let's take it from the top. Have you defined, _anywhere_, a new class for your exception, as I posted in my answer.

Comment: Azar: i did not define InvalidEmployeeId anywhere in the  sub class. I have no idea why am i getting this error.

Comment: can u explain more about putting super in the constructor please?

Comment: @user3080461 You are getting this error because **you must define** a new class for your exception! In order to `throw` `InvalidEmployeeId`, you have to create it first!

Comment: @user3080461 Because it extends `Exception`, I am calling the `Exception` constructor that takes a string. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Comment: i still can't figure out how to fix this. any thoughts please.

Comment: does the word after extends take the name of the demo program or it should always be Exception?

Comment: @user3080461 Everywhere in your code, use `InvalidEmployeeId`, with a capital I. Then, copy and paste my code for that class (`InvalidEmployeeId`) into a new class of the same name in your IDE. And yes, it should be `Exception`, as I have posted, and nothing else (for your purposes).